# Source code of the JavaScript 'Console' object and all its APIs

Tags: javascript, console

Is the implementation detail of the JavaScript Console object (the JavaScript debugging console that currently exists in all modern browsers) open-sourced?

Where can I find the source code of that Console object itself including all its API functions (e.g., `console.log()`, `console.info()`, `console.table()`, etc.)?

Who exactly develops or implements that Console object? Or do different browsers or JavaScript runtime environments implement this Console object in their own version of code which is not published, but according to a common standard or specification which defines all the attributes, APIs and behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers are open source, so is their implementation of the console "object". You may for example check out the Chromium project at https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code. The implementation varies between the different browsers, so do many of the JavaScript engine for example (Chrome has V8, Mozilla has Spidermonkey, ...)

What I assume you're really looking for is a definition of the API. This can easily be found for example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

Source: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-guide-to-javascript-engines-for-idiots/